# Unable to find an exact match for CDP - Cannot upload a file in SELENIUM & JAVA from windows popup

Tags: java, selenium, dependencies

I'm trying to select a file from a windows pop up in my multi-language page:

My code clicks on 2 buttons until the pop up is shown:

[image]

My CODE:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display:block;')", ele);
Thread.sleep(8000);
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='row attachment-files-item']//button[text()='Subir nuevo archivo']")).click();
//Thread.sleep(8000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"div-add-file\"]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("C:\\Users\\steve\\Downloads\\01004185FCA003900517097.pdf");
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 105, so returning the closest version found: 104
oct. 04, 2022 7:46:10 P. M. org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
Found CDP implementation for version 105 of 104
```

Is my code alright? am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error `Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 105, so returning the closest version found: 104` is not associated with the script but its associated with the `chrome version` being used

It seems you are using `chrome version 105` for that you will have to update the `dependencies` for `selenium-java` and `selenium-devtools-v105`

This is highlighted in release notes of `selenium 4.5` over [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG#L3)

Add following dependencies and check if that works fine(Remove older version for the dependency before adding new one)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java --> 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.0</version>
 </dependency>
   <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium- 
   devtools-v105 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v105</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note:- In case you are using a different version of chrome other than `105` select the corresponding dependency from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=Selenium%20Devtools) for devtools.
Also ensure you are using the correct version of chromed driver as per the current version of chrome installed on your system

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying.
Could you please take a look at the way i'm uploading a file?

Comment: @new_programmer can you share the page link where you are trying to  upload the file

Comment: The link itself no because it is not exposed :/